# Flight has been cancelled by airline but travel agent website still shows scheduled?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, covid-19

I have a flight (Flight number RS704, Air Seoul, Date:3rd April) that has been cancelled by the airline. They have released a notification about this on their official website.

But the online travel agent [(GoIbibo)](https://www.goibibo.com) that I used to book this ticket still shows the flight is operational. Currently because of the lockdown in India, Goibibo support is unstaffed and there is no way to reach them.

I don't want to cancel it on their website because I'm worried that normal cancellation charges would apply. Should I just wait until their offices open again (hopefully on 15th April)?

Comment: Have you reached out to Air Seoul about the cancellation?

Comment: @PeterM  No. But can they refund me if my ticket was booked by a travel agency?

Comment: What is your intention?  To be refunded for the flight or to re-book the flight at a different date?   Your original flight is cancelled and Golbibo can't change that.  But the airline will be trying to make arrangements for a new flight.  This should be able to be done without Golbibo being involved.  But those arrangements may only extend to either a rebooking or a voucher for future travel. But I'm not sure what happens these days in the era of COVID-19 - you may be eligible for a full refund.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.